# I have an array of objects, inside each object is key called scores, and I need to find the sum of each score and push it into an array

Tags: javascript

My console shows me the total of all the scores but I would like it to print 32 and 35 instead of 65. The end result is I want to push each total into an array.

```js
var peopleArray = [
    {
        name: "Hector Valdes",
        photo: "",
        scores: [
            "5", "1", 
            "4", "4", 
            "5", "1", 
            "2", "5", 
            "4", "1" 
        ]
    }, {
        name: "Tyler Williams",
        photo: "",
        scores: [
            "5", "1",
            "4", "4",
            "5", "2",
            "2", "5",
            "4", "1"
        ]
    }
]

let total = 0;

for (i = 0; i < peopleArray.length; i++){
        for(j=0; j < peopleArray[i].scores.length; j++){
            total += Number(peopleArray[i].scores[j]);
            console.log(total);
        };
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

> you need to move `total` in the first loop then just need to add a new total object in array

```
var peopleArray = [
    {
        name: "Hector Valdes",
        photo: "",
        scores: [
            "5", "1", 
            "4", "4", 
            "5", "1", 
            "2", "5", 
            "4", "1" 
        ]
    }, {
        name: "Tyler Williams",
        photo: "",
        scores: [
            "5", "1",
            "4", "4",
            "5", "2",
            "2", "5",
            "4", "1"
        ]
    }
];
console.log(peopleArray);
for (i = 0; i < peopleArray.length; i++){
     let total = 0;
     for(j=0; j < peopleArray[i].scores.length; j++){
        total += Number(peopleArray[i].scores[j]);
     };
     peopleArray[i]['total'] = total;
     console.log(total);
};
console.log(peopleArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var peopleArray = [
    {
        name: "Hector Valdes",
        photo: "",
        scores: [
            "5", "1", 
            "4", "4", 
            "5", "1", 
            "2", "5", 
            "4", "1" 
        ]
    }, {
        name: "Tyler Williams",
        photo: "",
        scores: [
            "5", "1",
            "4", "4",
            "5", "2",
            "2", "5",
            "4", "1"
        ]
    }
]

let total = peopleArray.map(i => {
  return i.scores.reduce((a, b) => parseInt(a) + parseInt(b), 0)
})
console.log(total)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` to loop thru each `peopleArray` element. Use `reduce` to sum the scores.

One option in converting a string to number by adding `+` before the string.

```js
var peopleArray = [{"name":"Hector Valdes","photo":"","scores":["5","1","4","4","5","1","2","5","4","1"]},{"name":"Tyler Williams","photo":"","scores":["5","1","4","4","5","2","2","5","4","1"]}];
var total = peopleArray.map(o => o.scores.reduce((c, v) => +c + +v));

console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const result = peopleArray.map((value) => {
    return {
        name: value.name,
        score: value.scores.reduce((total, score) => total + Number(score), 0)
    }

})
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is so clean so simple yet couldn't have thought of it thank you.

Comment: @TylerWilliams Please mark as correct answer if it solves your problem.  It can help to other as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Hope it helps..

```
let scoresArr = peopleArray.map(data => {   
return data.scores.reduce((a,b) => parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b), 0) 
})

console.log(scoresArr)
```